# What are these connector blocks called?

Tags: connector

This is from a key telephone system and im wondering what these connector blocks are called. Also, what type of tool should you use for these things?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a tool for these. You open the lid, insert the cable and close the lid. Then you insert the connector into the receptable.